# call "alert" from page in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

The page index.php has an "entrantes" button that, when clicked, loads another "platos" button in the corresponding div via ajax.
And what I want is that when I press that other button ("platos") I get the alert ("hola"), but that doesn't happen. where this error?

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div>
        <form  method="post" id="formulario">
        <input type="button" name="entrantes" value="Entrantes">
        </form>
    </div>
       
    <div id="platos_entrantes">
        
    </div>
    <div id="carrito">
        
    </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

ajax.js:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){       
    $('input[name=entrantes]').click(function(){
     var url = "buscar_platos.php";
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                     
       data: $("#formulario").serialize(), 
       success: function(data)             
       { 
         $('#platos_entrantes').html(data);  
       }
       });
    });
    
    $('input[name=plato]').click(function(){
       alert("hola");

    });
});
```

buscar_platos.php:

```
<input type="button" name="plato" value="Plato">
```

Comment: can you [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue in a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

i finally solved with this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#plato', function (evt) {
        alert("hola");
           });
```